# Call a method in loop until it has the expected results

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

the app use a method to check on the server every 5 minutes if there is the new content.
if there is the server return "true", else "false"

the question is how to call the method till the server returns "true" ? The moment when there is the new content will be a break to let the time to execute some code and after that the method should be called again to search new content on server.

i try that:

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

dispatch_async(q, ^{

    self.isNotifOnServer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self searchNewNotifications]];

    while (![self.isNotifOnServer isEqualToString:@"true"])
    {
        self.isNotifOnServer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self searchNewNotifications]];

        if ([self.isNotifOnServer isEqualToString:@"true"])
        {
            break;
            // Another method to get the notification
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSLog(@"The first search for notifications return %@", self.isNotifOnServer);

    });

});
```

Can you give me some advices, ideas ? Thank you

Comment: What happens when you run the code you have?

Comment: I wouldn't use a blocking while() loop like that, rather I'd call a priority_low queue on a server block, where the server will hold open the connection for up to five minutes or when its true condition is reached. Then I'd use an NSTimer to repeatedly call this routine.

Answer (score 0):

Use Recursion For that , define a method put your code in it , and create a perform selector !

```
-(void)myMethod{
 self.isNotifOnServer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self searchNewNotifications]];
 [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];  }
```

It will call the method in every 10 second !

You just need to call it once from viewDidLoad method once !

I hope this helps !